# Change order of records in TypeORM - Nestjs

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I need to save the order of products in `order` column of `product` table. Each time reorder one product, I must update `order` of all other products.

```js
  public async reorder(items: ProductDto[]) {
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      await this.productRepository.update(items[i].id, {
        order: items[i].order,
      });
    }
    return this.getAll();
  }
```

Do you have any suggestions for optimizing multiple savings?

Comment: If you know what item has changed, you could reorder only the items that come after it. So if you change the first item, you have to change everything, but if you change the last item, you don't have to reorder anyone.

Comment: You could also use a bulk insert to re-add everything to the database in a single command. This way you would probably be faster, but you would end up with an immutable table, so every time you change something, you add a new record instead of updating an existing one. So you have to take that into account on your queries.